# How to write array of one entity objects as a column into another entity in database schemas?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In  portfolio can be multiple stocks, and stock can be in multiple portfolios, so I choose many-to-mane relation. But as I understand to get stocks from portfolio, it will be needed  to use join between portfolioId and stockId. So I've been thinking that it will be good to store a massive of stocks in portfolio. How can I do it or what is the best way to store all stocks in portfolio?
[I have created such schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTc6f.png)

I am using postgresql. My code:

```
   create TABLE portfolio(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    years INTEGER NOT NULL,
    goal VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    analystId INTEGER,
    clientId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (analystId) REFERENCES analyst (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (clientId) REFERENCES client (id)
);

create TABLE portfolio_stock(
    stockId int NOT NULL,
    portfolioId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT portfolio_stockPK PRIMARY KEY(stockId, portfolioId),
    CONSTRAINT portfolio_stock_portfolioFK FOREIGN KEY(portfolioId) REFERENCES portfolio,
    CONSTRAINT portfolio_stock_stockFK FOREIGN KEY(stockId) REFERENCES stock
);

create TABLE portfolio_bond(
    bondId int NOT NULL,
    portfolioId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT portfolio_bondPK PRIMARY KEY(bondId, portfolioId),
    CONSTRAINT portfolio_bond_portfolioFK FOREIGN KEY(portfolioId) REFERENCES portfolio,
    CONSTRAINT portfolio_bond_bondkFK FOREIGN KEY(bondId) REFERENCES bond
);
```

Comment: "what is the best way to store all stocks in portfolio?" Sorry your question is unclear and your tables definition in Posgres doesn't correspond to your schema as an image. What do you want to achieve between your three tables Stocks, Portfolio, Portfolio_Stock ?

Comment: Trying to understand your ojective from the title, it would be a very bad idea to skip the table Portfolio_Stock and to directly store the stocks as an array in the Protfolio table.